# Laravel model's fillable against request validation rules

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5

I have been using laravel for a couple of times and when I used laravel 4 before, I used to add the rules for validation as a static member of the model. Like this one:

```
class Foo extends ValidatableModel
{
    protected static $rules = [
        'bar' => 'required'
    ];
}
```

The `ValidatableModel` extends Laravel's base `Model` and then has custom method to fill the attributes. I have no `fillable` property.

Now, in Laravel 5, I am not using this because of the further decoupling of validation which is good. With the advent of `Request` where you can specify the rules, I am now using the `fillable` property but I just don't like the duplication where you specify the field in the `fillable` property and then add the same field in the specific `Request` object. Too much work when adding/removing database fields.

I am of the mindset that a `fillable` property is a property that needs to be validated. Correct me if I am wrong here but so far, that has been my experience.

I have something in mind but I still have to test if it will work. Basically, I have to create my own base `Model` where I would set the values of `fillable` from a "corresponding" `Request` class (based on a naming convention). Something like below:

```
class FooRequest
{
    public static $_RULES = [
        'bar' => 'required'
    ];

    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return self::$_RULES;
    }
}

...

class ValidatableModel extends Model
{
    public $fillable = [];

    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::creating(function($model) {

            $requestClass = 'come up based on naming convention';
            $rules = $requestClass::$$_RULES;

            $model->fillable = array_keys($rules);
        });
    }
}
```

I don't know if this will work. I was just thinking about it and maybe I'll try it when I get home. And it looks like a lot of work just to eliminate the duplication in `fillable` property.

What do you guys think?

Comment: Is it so hard to look up the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#form-request-validation)?

Comment: i don't think it is in the docs if you really get what i am trying to achieve... is it in the docs on how to eliminate the duplication of fillable properties and a custom request object's rules... if so, please direct me to it by putting it as an answer...

Comment: Answering your own question is a viable option if you know the answer. BTW: what exact version of Laravel are you using? This Laravel 5 tag is unintentionally ambiguous

Comment: you can use custom request objects in laravel 5 where you can set validation rules.. it's not in laravel 4 and below... i still haven't tried what i just presented but i am open to ideas on how you guys do something different than what is presented in the docs...